# Excel Pivot Percentage Of Other Row Subtotal

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

Hi I wanted to get a %of another Row Subtotal so as shown on the above sample I wanted to do a calculation Cost by item divided with a Revenue Subtotal and get the percentage value of it. For Example on the image is  100/Subtotal Revenue (3000) , then 200/subtotal revenue (3000) how can i achieve this. Thanks

Comment: `=TEXT(100/3000,"0%")`

Comment: But This is pivot Table, where i wanted to have an auto calculation for the fields.

Comment: You're question is pretty unclear. You pretty much asked how to get 'a % of another row subtotal'. If this is not the actual question, then please [edit] and make it more clear to what you are wanting. And this is on the line of being off-topic and needing to go to [su].

Comment: Please next time insert the image in the question instead of a link. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @Mehdi New users do not have this ability, IIRC.

Comment: Hi so sorry i'm a newbie so still trying to do a correct posting. Now I see the image is showing up now. Hope can make the question more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the item:price:type table is located at A1:C5, put this in D2, then drag downwards..

```
=IF(C2="COST",TEXT(B2/SUMIF(C:C,"REVENUE",B:B),"0%"),"")
```

Hope it helps. ( :